# C++ for loop structure

Tags: c++

Hope its not a lame question but I have to ask this :)

When I program in C++ and use `for` loops the parameters I give are i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i< something; i++)
```

Which is correct way forward but..this gives me compile warnings such as this:

```
1>c:\main.cpp(185): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Now going through books and reading online most for loops examples are of this structure.

I was always ignoring warnings as my programs always worked and did what they suppose to do, until I got interested with this warnings and did a small research....by copying this Waring and Google it to find that it is better if I use this structure to avoid the warning:

```
for(vector<int>::size_type i= 0; i < something; i++ )
```

Now my question here is why......if the initial structure works and is described and documented in many books and online resources.

Also what is the benefit or is there any significant difference in the techniques.....?

Why would I use this

```
for(vector<int>::size_type i= 0; i < something; i++ )
```

apart from getting rid of the warnings.....?

Comment: Is `something` an `unsigned int`, or similar?

Comment: If `something` is not larger than `INT_MAX`, then `for(int i = 0; i < something; ++i)` will work correctly (unless `i` is modified in the loop body, then it could be set to a negative value and give an unexpected result for the comparison). But if `something > INT_MAX`, you will have undefined behaviour when `i++` overflows. Using the correct type for `i` avoids that possibility.

Comment: Ok I c thx people also the current application I am writing.....Is using Opencv Point data types and when i run a for loop i.e. `vector<Point> center`; then the loop looks like this `(int i = 0; i < center.size(); i++)` so i guess that the Point data type must be unsigned while int is signed.....

Comment: owww ye and for these that might not know Point datatype stores two int values one for x and one for y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ignore the warnings.  They're trying to tell you something.

I suspect `something` is unsigned.

If you have

```
unsigned int something = 0;
something--;  // Now something is a really large positive integer, not -1
```

If you ignore the warnings, and you don't have your compiler set to treat warnings as errors, then this will compile fine, but you won't get what you expect.

You're probably seeing that `vector<int>::size_type` is an `unsigned int` if the warning goes away.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have a `signed` / `unsigned` mismatch between the type of `i` and the type of `something` in your statement:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < something; i++)
```

So this has nothing to do with the `for` structure, but rather with the comparison.

```c
bool b = i < something;
```

would give you the same warnings.

This can be the case if you use `int i` and compare it to a `size_t` variable somehow (which is what `std::vector::size()` gives you).

So, to fix it, simply change your `for` loop to using the same type for `i` and for `something`, such as:

```c
for(size_t i = 0; i < something; i++)
```

if `something` is of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly, there are two kinds of integral types in C++: *signed* and *unsigned*. For each size of integer, there is a signed and an unsigned version. The difference is in their range: signed integers of *n* bits have a range from −2<sup>n − 1</sup> to +2<sup>n − 1</sup> − 1; unsigned integers, from 0 to 2<sup>n</sup> − 1.

When comparing signed integer types to unsigned, the signed value is converted to unsigned; negative values will *wrap* and be treated as large positive values. The upshot of this is that comparisons with `<` might not do what you expect, so many compilers will warn about such comparisons.

For example, `1u < -1` is true. `u` is a suffix that tells the compiler to treat the `1` as an `unsigned int` value.

With that, the meaning becomes clear: `int` is a signed type and `vector<T>::size_type` is an unsigned type. Since the result of `vector<T>::size()` is `vector<T>::size_type`, you want to use that or another unsigned type such as `size_t` to ensure that your comparisons have the behaviour you want.

Instead of using indices, you can also use iterators, which don’t have such conversion problems:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << '\n';
```

Which can be made more succinct with `auto` in C++11:

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << '\n';
```

If you’re just iterating over the whole container, use C++11 range-based `for`:

```
for (int i : v)
    cout << i << '\n';
```

And if you want to modify the values, use a reference:

```
for (int& i : v)
    ++i;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why would I use this

Because `signed int` and unsigned values like `size_t` have differing ranges, and you may not get your expected result if one contains a value that can not be represented by the other.

That said, if you think that code is *too verbose*, you don't have to use it.

Code like this:

```
for(vector<int>::size_type i= 0; i < myvector.size(); i++ )
{
    int val = myvector[i];
```

Can also be written like this.

```
for ( int val : myvector )
```

Answer (score 1):

`something` must be `int`, otherwise you get the warning. Or `i` must be `unsigned int`, depending on your needs.

Assuming a 32 bits integers, if signed any value above `0x7FFFFFFF` (`2,147,483,647 decimal`) will be interpreted as negative, whereas it will be positive for an `unsigned int`.

So the compiler is issuing a warning telling you that comparison mail result in unexpected outcome.

```
32 bits integers range from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
32 bits unsigned integers range from 0 to 4,294,967,295
```